# Form not updating values , validation fails but no errors

Tags: django, validation, python-2.7

I have a profile updation form , i have passed the data and instance to the form but the validation fails The scenarios are as follows .

This form is for profile updation , but the validation fails without showing any errors.

```
 class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile

    def clean(self):
        return self.cleaned_data
```

the view is as follows

**> The form.is_valid always returns False.**

```
def user_profile(request, params={}):
if request.user.is_staff==False:
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(request.POST,  instance=profile) 
        print profile_form.is_bound
        print profile_form.is_valid()
        if  profile_form.is_valid():
            profile = profile_form.save()
        else:
            pass
    else:
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm( instance=profile)  
    profile_form = ProfileEditForm( instance=profile)
    params['profile_form'] = profile_form
    return render_to_response('vec/profile.html', params, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    return render(request, 'base.html')
```

The following are the outputs :

> print profile_form.is_bound - returns True and 
>               print profile_form.is_valid() returns False .Also no erros in {{ profile_form.errors }} {{ profile_form.non_field_errors }}

Appreciate your reply... 
Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out ...

I just included the fields in the form definition

```
fields = ('','',)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are resetting `profile_form` before sending it to template, due to which no errors are shown.

See comments below

```
def user_profile(request, params={}):
    if request.user.is_staff==False:
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            profile_form = ProfileEditForm(request.POST,  instance=profile) 
            print profile_form.is_bound
            print profile_form.is_valid()
            if  profile_form.is_valid():
                profile = profile_form.save()
            else:
               pass
       else:
            profile_form = ProfileEditForm( instance=profile)  
       # don't do this, you already have profile_form
       #profile_form = ProfileEditForm( instance=profile)

       params['profile_form'] = profile_form
       return render_to_response('vec/profile.html', params, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
       return render(request, 'base.html')
```